# How do I resolve an error below in R when doing a Pearson correlation?

Tags: r, linear-regression, r-raster, pearson

This is the error message:

> "In writeBin(v, x@file@con, size = x@file@dsize) :   problem writing
>   to connection 6: In .rasterFromRasterFile(grdfile, band = band,
>   objecttype) :   size of values file does not match the number of cells
>   (given the data type)"

I have 15 raster files of the same extent and dimension.  I just want to find out the Correlation of this data across time (15 years) ie 15 raster files.

I used the script below:

```
list  <- c(list.files(pattern = "\\.tif$"))
y <- stack()
for  (i in 1:length(list)){
y <- stack(y,list[i]) }
corT <- layerStats(y, 'pearson', na.rm=TRUE)
```

OR
Used the stacked file directly like this

```
test = brick ("EOS_ALL_STACK.tif")

corT = layerStats(test, 'pearson', na.rm=TRUE)
```

I also tried to use this function to get correlation coefficients and r squared like this

```
fun5=function(x) { if (is.na(x[1])){ NA } else { m <- lm(x[1:15] ~ c(1:15));summary(m)$coefficients[1,4]}} #fstatistic[1]
fun5=function(x) { if (is.na(x[1])){ NA } else { m <- lm(x[1:15] ~ c(1:15));summary(m)$coefficients[2,4]}} #fstatistic[2]
fun3=function(x) { if (is.na(x[1])){ NA } else { m <- lm(x[1:15] ~ x[1:15]);summary(m)$r.squared }}
```

then used "calc" to calculate these across all pixels. For example:

```
r.squared <- calc(y, fun3)
```

However, my results still has the above errors and even when there is an output, it does not seem to make sense.

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Is your disk full?

Comment: I really have been trying to do this. My files are very large images of the entire African continent. I have been able to have really abridged version of them but still can't find a way to reproduce them here. Any tips please?

Comment: Disk full you mean my computer hard disk space?

Comment: Yes. Probably the disk of your temp folder. That would explain the "problem writing"

Comment: hmmmmmm...Interesting. I have been having issues with that. It shows I do not have any more available space, but I do not have any of my data stored on my C drive and also can't see of find what's in it, because I work from my external hard drive. Although softwares are installed on my computers C drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message:

```
writeBin(v, x@file@con, size = x@file@dsize) : problem writing to connection
```

Most likely indicates that your disk is full. This could be the disk of your working directory, or anywhere else you are writing a file. If you are not specifying a filename, you can check `tempfile()` to find the general location where temporary files are stored (the actual folder changes between sessions). You can change this via `rasterOptions()`. You can also avoid writing temporary files by providing a `filename=` argument to the raster functions.